# How do I delete a dm message that was sent by my discord bot

Tags: python

I did a script where you can send a message to a specific dm using my discord bot

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    message = message
    await user.send(message)
```

But how am I to make a script that can delete all messages that was sent by the bot in a specific dm

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the **`DMChannel.history()`** and delete the messages whose author is your client:

```
@client.command()
async def clear_dm(ctx, user: discord.User):
    async for message in user.dm_channel.history():
        if message.author == client.user:
            await message.delete()
```

Keep in mind that you need `read_message_history` and `manage_messages` permissions respectively, otherwise a `Forbidden` exception will be raised.
Also, maybe it's a good idea to catch `HTTPException` as well, to continue the iteration if the removal of any message fails for some reason.

Comment: I got this error raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'history'

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I fixed it. Here is the script

```
@client.command()
async def cleardm(ctx, user: discord.User):
    #await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1) remove '#' if you want the bot to delete the command you typed in the discord server
    async for message in user.history():
        if message.author == client.user:
            await message.delete()
```